# NSTableView start cells from bottom

Tags: swift, tableview

I have a osX project with NSTableview

```
[Screen]
[a]
[b]
[c]
[d]
no cell
no cell
[Screen]
```

is is posible to change direction of this tableview to look like this?

```
[Screen]
no cell
no cell
[d]
[c]
[b]
[a]
[Screen]
```

i have tried transform like in iOS but it throwing errors

```
tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
```

same goes for cell

```
cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
```

what must be done to access transform property in OSX like in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I think you want, you don't need to use `CGAffineTransform` .

You just need to organise your data set as you wish and populate the cells accordingly.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    cell.updateTitle(customCellTitles[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

instead of having your data set as:

`customCellTitles = ["a","b","c","d"]`

make it:

`customCellTitles = ["d","c","b","a"]`

In addition to this, I would go for the following setup of your layout:

[image]

Notice there is no top constraint.

Next, create an outlet from your table view height constraint and update it when you have your data set ready.

In the simple scenario where your cell size is the same (or independent from the content you display) update your height constraint based on the cell size:

```
tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = cellSize * numberOfCells
view.setNeedsLayout()
```

Comment: Is there a possibility that your screen size is smaller than your table view?
Also, keep in mind you can also scroll your table view to the bottom after you load it.
I will update the answer based on your response.

Comment: no... its table for menu. It does not scroll at all.